# Using far away for depth

Tags: word-choice, context, cloze-test

I was filling this cloze test from a book (the bolded words are answers):

> There are many methods of mining, **each of which** is based upon where a mineral deposit **is found** in the earth. While some mineral deposits are far ______, others lie at or **near** the earth['s] surface. Several different mining methods **are used when** deposit[s] occur close to the earth's surface.

Here are the choices for the blank:

> a. away
> b. deep
> c. from
> d. underground

I chose **underground** as the answer because it seems very logical and I don't suppose it will cause a grammatical error; however, the book says the correct answer is **away**. I can't find any way to relate **far away** to depth. Are there any? or is the book incorrect? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am a native English speaker and worked for a time on mining topics.  Without looking at the options, I immediately thought "underground".  I doubt that any mining engineer would refer to a deposit as "far away" in discussing the feasibility or cost of extracting a mineral.   One could say that the mining operation would be far away from, say, the nearest good restaurant (many of them are), but unless one is referring to an operation in the asteroid belt, "far away" makes no sense in describing the location of a mining operation.  One wonders what else the book got wrong.  Good to question!

Comment: Correction to previous comment:  The site could be "far away from the nearest road or rail-head",  so that a road would have to be built and/or a spur rail line built.  This would affect the cost of extracting the mineral.

Comment: Bury the book far underground and far away. After using it as fuel in a blast furnace. Assuming that '... others lie at or near the earth surface ...' and '... different mining methods are used when deposit occur close ...' actually appeared in the original.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is probably caused by a typo in the book -- (d) should have been the correct answer, no doubt about it.

Comment: @ab2 why don't you write your comments as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: @Amen Thank you for offering to accept my comment if I write it as an answer.  I appreciate it!  However, your question is likely to be closed because I and other users think your book had a typo -- if the book had been proofread just a bit better, d would have been marked as the answer.  It is not kosher to answer questions that one knows are going to be closed.